# Why are my semaphores allowing out-of-order events within forked processes?

Tags: c, semaphore

I am trying to make a program that counts from 0 to whatever number is input in the command line in C. In this program, there has to be two fork() calls, making a total of 3 processes. I have to then use a minimum of 1 semaphore to ensure that the processes run in numerical order with each one in charge of a different n % 3.

The issue I am having is that despite the semaphores I'm using, the program seems to run out of order on a fairly regular basis. I am currently using a gate-style system where each process will force it's own designated semaphore to wait, and once finished, sem_post the semaphore of the process that is supposed to run next. I know this is not the prettiest or most logically efficient way of doing this, but it is one that I was pretty sure would work after my first two different attempts that got this same issue.

If anyone can give me any suggestions as to where I have gone so wrong, I would very much appreciate it.

My code is below:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <semaphore.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>

    #define SEM_NAME1 "/sem1.mutex"
    #define SEM_NAME2 "/sem2.mutex"
    #define SEM_NAME3 "/sem3.mutex"

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

        if(argc <= 1){
            printf("No arguments were provided so there is no number to count to");
            return 1;
        }

        // Create the 3 semaphores needed
        sem_t *sem1;
        sem_t *sem2;
        sem_t *sem3;

        //initialize to 0
        sem1 = sem_open(SEM_NAME1, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 0);
        if (sem1==SEM_FAILED) {
            printf("%s sem_open failed!", SEM_NAME1);
            return (-1);
        }
        //initialize to 1
        sem2 = sem_open(SEM_NAME2, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 1);
        if (sem2==SEM_FAILED) {
            printf("%s sem_open failed!", SEM_NAME2);
            return (-1);
        }
        //initialize to 1
        sem3 = sem_open(SEM_NAME3, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 1);
        if (sem3==SEM_FAILED) {
            printf("%s sem_open failed!", SEM_NAME3);
            return (-1);
        }

        pid_t pid;
        pid_t pid2;
        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0){
            pid2 = fork();
        }
        // Shared fork variables
        int counter = 0;
        int ranOnce = 0;
        int max_num = atoi(argv[1]);

        while(counter <= max_num){
            if(pid > 0){
                printf("%d",getpid());
                if(ranOnce == 0){
                    counter += 1;
                    ranOnce = 1;
                }
                sem_wait(sem2);
                printf(" %d \n", counter);
                counter += 3;
                sem_post(sem3);
            }
            else if(pid2 == 0){
                printf("%d",getpid());
                if(ranOnce == 0){
                    counter += 0;
                    ranOnce = 1;
                }
                sem_wait(sem1);
                printf(" %d \n", counter);
                counter += 3;
                sem_post(sem2);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d",getpid());
                if(ranOnce == 0){
                    counter += 2;
                    ranOnce = 1;
                }
                sem_wait(sem3);
                printf(" %d \n", counter);
                counter += 3;
                sem_post(sem1);
            }
        }
        //sem_unlink(SEM_NAME1);
        //sem_unlink(SEM_NAME2);
        //sem_unlink(SEM_NAME3);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semaphore initial values must be the inverse

```
sem1 = sem_open(SEM_NAME1, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 1);
sem2 = sem_open(SEM_NAME2, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 0);
sem3 = sem_open(SEM_NAME3, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 0);
```

You are currently activate sem2 and sem3 processes at the same time, so they work concurrently, but you need to synchronize them for removing out of ordering events.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your code can't work as designed.

After the `fork` calls, each process has its own private copy of the "shared" variables. Unlike a thread, you'll have to use shared memory regions you set up via SysV shared memory primitives.

So, each process is incrementing its own copy, and *not* a shared copy of `counter`.

Also, *all* access to shared variables [including the `while` clause] must be encapsulated in locks.

---

> I'm not sure if you are implying in the third sentence that I want to use a shared variable or that I should be using the individual copies.

I was looking at your comment: `// Shared fork variables`, so I inferred that you *wanted* a common counter. IMO, you *do* want one as a cross-check

> I am aware that each is only accessing their own individual copy of the counter variable and that is the purpose of the semaphore gates. When the thread is allowed to run again, it means that both other processes have done their print, so the next character in the sequence will be 3 ahead of the current value of counter.

I had recoded your app to simplify it so I could understand it.

I'm not seeing a clean round robin sequence. If you are, now, all is well, and I might have introduced a bug. I added a shared memory global counter using `shmget` et. al. and it should increment by one, but it occasionally slips backwards [*Caveat:* It's late here and I'm tired, so that may be part of the issue :-)]

Anyway, here's what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

#define SEM_NAME1 "/sem1.mutex"
#define SEM_NAME2 "/sem2.mutex"
#define SEM_NAME3 "/sem3.mutex"

typedef struct tsk {
    int tsk_idx;
    sem_t *tsk_sem;
    pid_t tsk_pid;
    char tsk_name[100];
} tsk_t;

#define NTASK       3

tsk_t tsklist[NTASK];

// Shared fork variables
volatile int counter = 0;
volatile int ranOnce = 0;
int max_num;
volatile int *globptr;

void
dochild(tsk_t *tsk)
{
    int stopflg;
    int tidx;
    tsk_t *tsk2;

    while (1) {
        sem_wait(tsk->tsk_sem);
        stopflg = (counter > max_num);

        if (! stopflg) {
            printf("Tidx:%d Pid:%d Seq:%d",tsk->tsk_idx,tsk->tsk_pid,*globptr);
            *globptr += 1;
            if (ranOnce == 0) {
                counter += 1;
                ranOnce = 1;
            }
            printf(" Counter:%d\n", counter);
            fflush(stdout);
            counter += 3;
        }

        tidx = tsk->tsk_idx + 1;
        tidx %= NTASK;
        tsk2 = &tsklist[tidx];

        sem_post(tsk2->tsk_sem);

        if (stopflg)
            break;
    }

    exit(0);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    tsk_t *tsk;
    int tidx;
    void *sptr;

    if (argc <= 1) {
        printf("No arguments were provided so there is no number to count to\n");
        //return 1;
    }
    else
        max_num = atoi(argv[1]);

    int shmfd = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0600);
    sptr = shmat(shmfd,NULL,0);
    globptr = sptr;
    *globptr = 0;

    // Create the 3 semaphores needed
    for (tidx = 0;  tidx < NTASK;  ++tidx) {
        tsk = &tsklist[tidx];
        tsk->tsk_idx = tidx;

        sprintf(tsk->tsk_name,"/sem%d.mutex",tidx);

        if (max_num == 0) {
            sem_unlink(tsk->tsk_name);
            continue;
        }

        tsk->tsk_sem = sem_open(tsk->tsk_name, O_CREAT, O_RDWR,
            0644,(tidx == 0) ? 1 : 0);

        if (tsk->tsk_sem == SEM_FAILED) {
            printf("%s sem_open failed! -- %s\n",tsk->tsk_name,strerror(errno));
            return (-1);
        }
    }

    if (max_num == 0)
        return 0;

    for (tidx = 0;  tidx < NTASK;  ++tidx) {
        tsk = &tsklist[tidx];
        tsk->tsk_pid = fork();
        if (tsk->tsk_pid != 0)
            continue;

        tsk->tsk_pid = getpid();
        dochild(tsk);
    }

    for (tidx = 0;  tidx < NTASK;  ++tidx) {
        tsk = &tsklist[tidx];
        waitpid(tsk->tsk_pid,NULL,0);
    }

#if 1
    for (tidx = 0;  tidx < NTASK;  ++tidx) {
        tsk = &tsklist[tidx];
        sem_unlink(tsk->tsk_name);
    }
#endif

    shmdt(sptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output of a run:

```
Tidx:0 Pid:18563 Seq:0 Counter:1
Tidx:0 Pid:18563 Seq:1 Counter:4
Tidx:0 Pid:18563 Seq:2 Counter:7
Tidx:0 Pid:18563 Seq:3 Counter:10
Tidx:1 Pid:18564 Seq:4 Counter:1
Tidx:1 Pid:18564 Seq:5 Counter:4
Tidx:1 Pid:18564 Seq:6 Counter:7
Tidx:1 Pid:18564 Seq:7 Counter:10
Tidx:2 Pid:18565 Seq:4 Counter:1
Tidx:2 Pid:18565 Seq:9 Counter:4
Tidx:2 Pid:18565 Seq:10 Counter:7
Tidx:2 Pid:18565 Seq:11 Counter:10
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you are implying in the third sentence that I want to use a shared variable or that I should be using the individual copies. I am aware that each is only accessing their own individual copy of the counter variable and that is the purpose of the semaphore gates. When the thread is allowed to run again, it means that both other processes have done their print, so the next character in the sequence will be 3 ahead of the current value of counter.